# How to fetch attribute value from XML

Tags: xml

My XML is

````
<output>
<line index="1">Count:3</line>
<line index="2">Avg:0</line>
<line index="3">Sum:13</line>
<line index="4">property:7</line>
</output>```
````

result I want is "Sum:13", its not necessary the result will be at attribute 3, it can be placed anywhere in the XML

Comment: use xpath: `//*[@index=3]/text()`

Comment: the value sum can be anywhere along the XML, not necessary it will be at 3. please note "sum" is static value and I have to fetch value "Sum" form anywhere in the XML